# Импорт модуля и вызов функции из этого модуля по имени функции

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-2.7, импорт

Добрый день,
Столкнулся с такой проблемой, из файла настроек считываем название импортируемого модуля (может находится где угодно), также считываем название функции, которую необходимо выполнить после импорта модуля.

теперь собственно вопрос, каким образом вызвать функцию из файла *.py если заранее не известно что это за функция???

к примеру есть скрипт /tmp/test/test.py с содержимым:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import time
def start(text=None):
    print u'Внешний скрипт', text
    print u'Запуск в ', time.time()
```

запускаю другой скрипт, в котором собственно и выполняется загрузка функции:

```
import imp
funcName = 'start'
modulePath = '/tmp/test/test.py'
mod = imp.load_source(funcName, modulePath)
```

а вот каким образом осуществить вызов функции осуществить не понятно мне, ибо мне изначально не известно как называется функция.

Я так понимаю что должен быть способ, но найти пока не удалось

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В `load_source` первым параметром указывается имя модуля, а не имя функции.

Так как любой модуль по сути является объектом, то можно воспользоваться методом `getattr`. Простой пример:

```
import math

cos = getattr(math, "cos")
print(cos)
print(cos(-3.14))

if hasattr(math, "sin"):
    sin = getattr(math, "sin")
    print(sin)
    print(sin(3.14))
```

В вашем случае надо написать:

```
start = getattr(mod, funcName)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, я как раз на это наткнулся, проверил, работает

Comment: Да конечно, не класс, а объект. Спасибо за замечание.